# finding the CSRF token inside an html page using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The HTML looks something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:SOME_TOKEN"/>
```

I've tried this a few different ways, but I keep getting an error. I thought this way looked right, but apparently not.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
soup.find('input', {'name':'csrfToken'})
```

I keep getting:

```
TypeError: 'expected string or buffer'
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way of extracting the CSRF token from the given input:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:SOME_TOKEN"/>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

token = soup.find('input', {'name':'csrfToken'})['value']

print token
```

The result from running this is:

```
ajax:SOME_TOKEN
```

By looking at your example, the actual extraction of the html element seems correct. Can it be that your `html_page` is not set or some other kind of type (i.e. not a string) ?

Comment: gaaah..that was it. I was doing BeautifulSoup(r) instead of BeautifulSoup(r.text)

Comment: That is an easy mistake to make, glad that you sorted it out :)